# Named route with arguments to a stateful widet

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have a stateful widget which is associated to a named route:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Steady Calendar',
        initialRoute: Splash.routeName,
        routes: {
          ...
          CalEdit.routeName: (_) => const CalEdit(),
          ...
```

`CalEdit` is called when - well - the user wants to edit a calendar, as well as a new calendar is being created by the user. the calendar is passed as an argument to the navigation:

```dart
onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, CalEdit.routeName, arguments: CalEditArguments(null)),
```

in case `null` is passed it means we wanna create a brand new calendar. What I want is figuring out just once if a non-null calendar is passed, but `initState` is a bad place (the context is not there already I guess?) and `build` should check this each time the component is rendered. yak! I'm wondering if there's a best practice for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement **onGenerateRoute:** instead of **routes:** for best practice with name router. You could extract your arguments from **RouteSettings** and set it for **Target Widget**.

```
onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
    var routes = <String, WidgetBuilder>{
      ......
      CalEdit.routeName: (_) => const CalEdit(initialValue: settings.arguments as String),
      ......
    };

    WidgetBuilder? builder = routes[settings.name];

    if (builder != null) {
      return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (ctx) => builder(ctx),
          settings: RouteSettings(name: settings.name));
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```